# Suspend USB drive in bash

Tags: usb

I'm setting up a Linux machine (Ubuntu 9.10) as a file server on my LAN and want to have a few of my external hard drives attached to it, but not always powered up. I've read that I can suspend USB devices ([here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/usb-pen-drive-flash-drive-unmounted-but-the-power-is-there-503208/) and [here](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/devices-power-management/usb.php)) and this will power down the device until I want to wake it up later. Since my external drives are hard disks I think this will greatly extend their lifespan!

I want to make sure before I go ahead and run the commands that I'm doing exactly the right thing. I want to suspend the device at `/dev/sdc1`:

```
$ udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdc1
# output: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
$ echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/1-4:1.0/host3/power/level
```

Then to turn the device back on:

```
echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/1-4:1.0/host3/power/level
```

Can someone confirm that I am writing the 'suspend' command to the correct file? Do I need to unmount the drive before I suspend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying some things out i found that the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/1-4:1.0/host3/power/level` file actually did not exist.

the correct file was actually located at `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/power/level` which is far more logical - just add a `/sys` to the start of the output from the `udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdc1` command.

echoing `suspend` to this file will suspend the external hard drive - all the lights go off and it uses low power.

then echoing `on` to the same location will wake it up again!

now i can leave all my drives plugged in to my lan pc and suspend them until i want to use them `:)`